# Получение элемента json массива

Tags: json, lua

есть json файл по типу

```
{
   "response":{
      "count":2,
      "items":[
         { "something":1},
         { "something":2}
      ]
 }
}
```

Как получить первый something используя библиотеку dkjson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по примеру в http://dkolf.de/src/dkjson-lua.fsl/home

Думаю, примерно, так:

```lua
local json = require ("dkjson")

local str = [[
{
   "response":{
      "count":2,
      "items":[
         { "something":1},
         { "something":2}
      ]
 }
}
]]

local obj, pos, err = json.decode (str, 1, nil)
if err then
  print ("Error:", err)
else
  for i = 1,#obj.response.items do
    print (i, obj.response.items[i].something)
  end
end
```